# ggplot error bar not showing on graph because it falls outside y axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot with pre-defined Y-axis limits.
I noticed that when error bars exceed these Y-axis bounds, the entire error bar is *not* plotted, rather than just clipping it to the Y-axis bound.

An example, using the ToothGrowth data set (see also http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/):

```
df <- ToothGrowth
dfc <- summarySE(df, measurevar="len", groupvars=c("supp","dose"))  
ggplot(dfc, aes(x=dose, y=len, colour=supp)) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=len-se, ymax=len+se), width=.1) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(7.5,26.5))
```

I want the error bars at the dose=2.0 point start at their bottom point (note that the horizontal marker line is there), and run all the way up to the border of the plot (i.e., the Y-axis upper limit). How can I achieve this? (Similarly for the dose=0.5 point in the VC series.)

Comment: Setting the limits in the `scale` function drops data outside the range; setting limits using `coord_cartesian` does a simple zoom.